# Fallout Shelter Kids in 3 Hours?

Tags: fallout-shelter

Is it 3 hours in-game time or 3 hours real time? I have played for over 6 hours of actual play time, I have 7 women pregnant and none of them have delivered.

Comment: I think this is a duplicate. As noted in the answers from the other question, you need enough housing space for children to be born.

Comment: If you go at the room level (living quarters), you can actually see the girl talking about the fact that there isn't enough room in the vault to start a family, provided she has who to talk to :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably need more living quarters.  If you don't have enough vault space then all the pregnant ladies just stay prego until there are enough living quarters for their new children.